# AWS EC2 Ubuntu don't support ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2

I run 2 selenium python3 with ProcessPoolExecutor

In my desktop, It works normally.

But In Ubuntu with t2.micro , only one selenium run and ubuntu don't print errors.

selenium only use 200MB memory. What's the problem?

t2.micro's cpu power is so low to run two selenium?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

if __name__ == '__main__':

    executer = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    argvs = [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
    ]
    for argv in argvs:
        executer.submit(main, argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaed can run like below

```
#test.py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('python3 1.py&', sheel=True)
subprocess.Popen('python3 2.py&', sheel=True)
```